# facing trouble giving user option to unmute autoplaying vimeo iframe embed

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, vimeo

before you jump to any conclusions-- I know that due to a recent chrome update, videos that are autoplaying can not play audio without the user interacting with the page.
My problem stems from the fact that the autoplaying video in question refuses to be unmuted and pauses instead, even if the user Has interacted with the page. I think it's something to do with the fact that it's a video embedded from Vimeo, so I want to know what I can do to fix my problem.

mockup of problem i'm facing:
[link](https://archizzl.com/muteproblem)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your example (nice touch, very helpful by the way), if I click on the video a couple of times and then click on your button, the Vimeo video unmutes as expected (no errors).

If you re-read the doc that Chrome linked to as part of your stated error (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) you'll note:

> Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>
> - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).

The key thing to note is **domain**.

An iframe is a different domain than the hosting page (where the click, aka interaction, is happening). This is likely why your second video, which is hosted on your domain (the same domain that the user is interacting with on click), is working.

That is the why, I am not sure what the workaround would be, it would likely require allowing the user to unmute the video using the player controls in the player. I'll be curious to know what workaround you come up with.